# I want the method_decorator to be overwritten whenever my Test is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This is my test function that i am using to test this is the solution i get to patch the method_decorator but its not working for me

I am not able to get into view because there is a decorator above the class that is wrapping the class and i am not able to patch or override it

This is my TestCase code

```
class ClientActivityTestCase(APITestCase):
    def mock_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        """Decorate by doing nothing."""

        def decorator(f):
            @wraps(f)
            def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

            return decorated_function

        return decorator

    # PATCH THE DECORATOR HERE
    @patch('adminportal.views.super_admin_login_required', mock_decorator)
    def test_client_activity_view_get(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("client_activity_report"), HTTP_ORIGIN=settings.HOST_NAME, format='json')
        print(response)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertIn("Client Activity Report", response.content.decode())
```

and this is my code in view

```
@method_decorator(super_admin_login_required, name="dispatch")
class ClientActivityReport(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ClientColumnForm(
            initial={
                "columns": [
                    "organization",
                    "location",
                    "client",
                    "leads",
                    "organic",
                    "trials",
                    "zoho",
                    "website_status",
                    # "keyword",
                    # "ranking",
                ]
            }
        )
        return render(
            request,
            "reports/client_activity_report.html",
            {
                "three_months": get_last_three_months(),
                "countries": State.objects.filter(
                    parent_state__isnull=True
                ).values_list("name", flat=True),
                "orders": [
                    "Leads",
                    "Trials",
                    "Organic Leads",
                    "Target Location",
                    "Organization Name",
                ],
                "form": form,
            },
        )
```

This is the code of my permission class

```
def super_admin_login_required(
    function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None
):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_superuser
        and (not u.is_anonymous)
        and (u.get_role_display() == "superadmin"),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Comment: `super_admin_login_required` is called when `ClientActivityReport` is defined, presumably when the module containing it is imported. By the time you are defining your test case, it is too late to patch the name, because it won't be called again.

Comment: then what is the solution to it

Comment: Either enable the patch *before* you import the code to test, or refactor your code so that you can apply `method_decorator` manually in your module and `mock_decorator` manually in your test module, instead of using decorator syntax to hide the original, undecorated class.